# awk: print columns with original format

Tags: awk

I know it is really a naive question. I knew it in the past but forgot how to do it. Tried searching but all the answers were very complex.. couldnt find what I was looking for so please help me!

I have a data that is separated by tab and i only want to print lets say 3 columns out of 5 original columns so i did:

awk '{print $1 $3 $5}' infile >> outfile

but it destorys the tab separated format.

Can someone remind me how to do this and still keep the original format?

original data:

```
ABC   1   343   122   234
DEF   1   342   122   163
GHI   1   342   643   422
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want tab separated output

```
awk  'BEGIN{OFS="\t";} {print $1,$3,$5}' infile >> outfile
```

Comment: Could be shorten some: `awk {print $1,$3,$5}' OFS=\t infile >> outfile`